# Google Roads API "Requested entity was not found"

Tags: google-roads-api

I am trying to use the Google Roads API but it is returning an error when I use the example!

If I type the following URL into my browser I get the following response:

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=51.4907313,-0.2160447|51.4905303,-0.2139847&key=*******
```

I have replaced my API key with asterisks for obvious reasons.

Response:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Please note that I am a newbie regarding Google APIs.

Comment: ***Notice**: The Speed Limit service is available to all customers with an Asset Tracking license.* - First line of the docs. You have that? If yes, ask Google support.

Comment: Did you find a solution becasue im having the same issue on android ?

Answer (score 4):

You most likely do not have a billing Account associated to your Google API project. The same thing happened to me. Since I have set up a billing account and added this to the API project the requests are working as expected.

See: 
[How to add a Google billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account) and
[How to modify a projects billig account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project)

Comment: I don't undestand why this answer was downvoted. This actually solved my issue when I got 404 message when using snapToRoads API. Although it doesn't match with google troubleshooting as they claim that you should get 403 instead, which makes things a bit more confusing. But nevertheless, this solved my 404 error

Comment: Isn't there anyway to test the Roads API without setting up a billing account? I just want to try it, not to use it.

Comment: No, I doubt it. I had to set one up in order to test it. However, it is free.